# Strings to Classes Java

Tags: java, android, class

I'm writing an Android app that has a drawing feature, and allows users to pick different brushes to draw with. At one point, when the brushes are changed, I have the following method:

```
public Brush newBrush(String className){
    Brush currentBrush;
    switch (className){
        case "StandardBrush":
            currentBrush = new StandardBrush(currentColor, currentSize);
            break;
        case "SquareBrush":
            currentBrush = new SquareBrush(currentColor, currentSize);
            break;
        case "Highlighter":
            currentBrush = new Highlighter(currentColor, currentSize);
            break;
        case "AirBrush":
            currentBrush = new AirBrush(currentColor, currentSize);
            break;
        case "PaintBrush":
            currentBrush = new PaintBrush(currentColor, currentSize);
            break;
        case "CalligraphicBrush":
            currentBrush = new CalligraphicBrush(currentColor, currentSize);
            break;
        case "VanishingBrush":
            currentBrush = new VanishingBrush(currentColor, currentSize);
            break
    }
    return currentBrush;
}
```

If I choose to add more options later on, this switch statement could get very long. So is there a way to shorten it? Such as converting a string into a Class and then just creating a new instance of that class?

Comment: you are doing the same thing in all switch case statements. There is no switch required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would probably be a performance hit, but you could use reflection.
Something like:

```
 return Class.forName(className).getConstructors()[0].newInstance(color, size);
```

Comment: Based on the fact that the 'user' initiates a brush change the 'performance hit' would completely negligible (O(1) and infrequent at that) (ie it's okay to do something 'slow' if you don't do it often)

Comment: I also agree about the performance hit being acceptable when in response to a user action as the delay will most likely not be noticable, but it is far from O(1). It is dependent on the classloader which can be as fast as O(log n) if the class is already in the hashmap where N is the number of classes in the classloader, but may be slower if the class has yet to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a factory class to "hide" the switch (which is still big, but it is localiazed in one place)

```
class BrushFactory()
{
    static Brush getBrush(string type, int color, int size)
    {
        switch (className){
        case "StandardBrush":
            return new StandardBrush(currentColor, currentSize);
        case "SquareBrush":
            return new SquareBrush(currentColor, currentSize);
        ...
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through Java Reflection.

```
public Brush newBrush(String className){
    try {
        Class<? extends Brush> brushClass = (Class<? extends Brush>)Class.forName(className);
        Constructor<? extends Brush> constructor = brushClass == null ? null : brushClass.getConstructor(Color.class, int.class); // Argument types need to be changed to whatever currentColor and currentSize are
        return constructor == null ? null : constructor.newInstance(currentColor, currentSize);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Edit: The above made the assumption of no package, which you may need to prepend. Here's how to do it if they are in the same package:

```
String p = getClass().getName();
p = p.substring(0, p.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
Class.forName(p + className);
```

Answer (score 0):

## A possible approach

### Considerations

- move away from switch case
- Do you really want to instantiate a new Brush object? Consider re-using an existing (already instantiated object)
- Set the color and size after the brush is instantiated?

### Approach:

When your app starts initialize all brushes in a Map. You can look at brushes as a dependency that your app needs to do its work.
When a brush is selected by name retrieve it from the map.

So you will typically have `BrushMap.get("*<BrushName>*")`

You can consider encapsulating it in a Factory so that you can still change the approach later if you don't find it useful or want to change it for any reason.

So in the end you will have:
 - In constructor of the BrushFactory, you would load all brushes into a map
 - The getBrush method in BrushFactory will retrieve the object from map and set color and size to it

### **Notes:**

1. Consider the [Prototype design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern) if you must have a new copy every time
2. There is probably a reflection solution to this too.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Ah! by the time I typed this out... the reflection solution was already out there :D.